# In $\mathbb R^3$ determine the graph of $span \{(1, 3, 2), (2, 6, 4), (-3, -9, -6)\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a+2b-3c=x \\ 
3a+6b-9c=y \\ 
2a+4b-6c=z
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

This suggests that all the vectors in the span have the shape of $(x, 3x, 2x) = x(1, 3, 2)$. So the graph of the given span is a line through the origin in three-dimensional space.

Does this explanation make sense?

Comment: It makes sense but you can use a simpler argument by noticing the linear dependency in the three vectors.

Comment: Indeed, as Henry W says, $(2, 6, 4) = 2(1, 3, 2), (-3, -9, -6) = -3(1, 3, 2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is correct. An algorithmic way of solving problems like this is to put the given vectors in the rows of a matrix and row reduce. In this case we have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref
\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&2\\ 2&6&4\\ -3&-9&-6
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&2\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
This tells us that 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{\langle1,3,2\rangle,\langle2,6,4\rangle,\langle-3,-9,-6\rangle\}=
\Span\{\langle 1,3,2\rangle\}
$$
That is, the space in question is the line in $\Bbb R^3$ that passes through the origin and the point $(1,3,2)$.